# Overriding default hashes without merging

Tags: chef-infra, logstash, chef-solo

I'm attempting to use the chef-logstash cookbook at [lusis/chef-logstash](https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash/tree/logstash_1.4) and am having a hard time overriding the `['logstash']['instance']['server']['config_templates']` attribute. When I set this via my wrapper cookbook at [wrapper-logstash](https://github.com/davidski/cookbooks/blob/logstash_1.4/wrapper-logstash/recipes/server.rb), I get a merged hash of the default as well as what I added in via my wrapper recipe.

For reference, the code I'm using in my recipe is:

```
#force override our attributes (or attempt to anyways)
#attributes = node['logstash']['instance'][name]
node.force_override['logstash']['instance']['server']['config_templates'] = {}
node.force_override['logstash']['instance']['server']['config_templates'] = {
   'input_redis' => 'config/input_redis.conf.erb',
   'filter_sidewinder' => 'config/filter_sidewinder.conf.erb',
   'output_elasticsearch' => 'config/output_elasticsearch.conf.erb'
}
```

How can I cleanly override this attribute to be set only to what's in my wrapper cookbook?

Comment: https://coderanger.net/2013/06/arrays-and-chef/

Comment: Thanks, Seth. That was one of the blogs that I came across when trying to research this issue. :) That posting talks about how hashes are superior to arrays for both additions and deletions, but I don't see an example in the post on how to do the deletions, nor do I see anything that suggests the code from above is incorrect. I suspect I'm being dense on something, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what. :(

Comment: You can't... That's what Noah is saying. You need to set them to `nil`

Comment: I'd also recommend asking John Vincent about it. It's his cookbook, and this question seems more appropriate for a GitHub issue to be answered by the author than Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'll follow up with John as you suggest. To clarify, hashes can only be merged in chef. Keys can never be deleted, even with force_override? That seems very awkward.

Comment: Depends on the way the attribute is created. There's a difference between a hash and a mash too.

Comment: In this case, the source LWRP cookbook is just doing a straight default['logstash']...foo... = {}, which looks like a hash. Googling suggests that mashes (hashes that retain their default values) are created via explicit class assignment at variable definition time. Still hoping someone can state definitively if a default hash (not a mash) in a cookbook is something to which keys can be changed or added, but not something from which keys can be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

After quite a bit of help from the @LearnChef crew, the solution was to use ruby code in my wrapper recipe to iterate over the keys and delete them. A gotchya was ensuring that the iterate and delete loop was using the same attribute precedence level as the original default attribute, which were set in the source LWRP not at the default level, but at the normal level.

Final code looks like:

```
#clear out the default config templates
attributes = node['logstash']['instance'][name]
node.normal['logstash']['instance'][name]['config_templates'].keys.each do |k|
  node.normal['logstash']['instance'][name]['config_templates'].delete(k)
end
node.force_override['logstash']['instance']['server']['config_templates'] = {
  'input_redis' => 'config/input_redis.conf.erb',
  'filter_sidewinder' => 'config/filter_sidewinder.conf.erb',
  'output_elasticsearch' => 'config/output_elasticsearch.conf.erb'
}
```

Comment: At this point, you could also just supply your own template and ignore those variables in it.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar use-case, I just wanted to set my hash to an empty hash. A quick & dirty workaround that worked for me was to set the attribute to an **empty array**, like so:

*Original attribute definition:*

```
#give us an elasticsearch cluster with these plugins by default
default['elasticsearch']['plugins'] = {
  'karmi/elasticsearch-paramedic' => {},
  'mobz/elasticsearch-head' => {},
  'jlinn/elasticsearch-cloud-rackspace' => {
    'url' => 'https://github.com/jlinn/elasticsearch-cloud-rackspace/releases/download/v0.4.1/elasticsearch-cloud-rackspace-0.4.1.zip'
  }
}
```

My definition in the environment:

```
"elasticsearch": {
  "plugins": []
}
```

And this is the code that was using that:

```
node[:elasticsearch][:plugins].each do | name, config |
  next if name == 'elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws' && !node.recipe?('aws')
  next if name == 'elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-gce' && !node.recipe?('gce')
  install_plugin name, config
end
```

Just putting this out there in case you're also looking for a quick/temporary hack. Hope it helps!